# How to instantiate prefab after specified prefab have been instantiated?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have Enemy.cs to stochastically instantiate enemies.
Then I want to get a hero.cs to instantiate heroes.

The requirement is to instantiate the hero following the corresponding enemy.
For example, find enemy_01 in scene, then instantiate hero_01.
Find enemy_02 in scene, then instantiate hero_02.
Without enemy_03, hero_03 should not be instantiated.

Even harder, I want to choose which hero to be instantiated.
For example, with enemy_01 in scene, 80 % chance to instantiate hero_01, 20 % chance to instantiate hero_02.
With enemy_02 in scene, 50 % chance to instantiate hero_02, 50 % chance to instantiate hero_03.
But without enemy_03, hero_03 can not be instantiated.

Could you give me an idea or thinking?

My Hero.cs

```
using UnityEngine;

using System.Collections;

using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Hero_list : MonoBehaviour 
{
    [System.Serializable]
    public class Hero
    {
        public GameObject Hero_prefab;
        public GameObject Need_prefab;
    }
    public List <Hero> Heroes = new List <Hero> ();
    public static Hero_list instance;

    public void findEnemy()
    {
        GameObject[] respawns = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Enemy");

        foreach (GameObject respawn in respawns)
        {
            Debug.Log(respawn);

        }
    }


    void Update () 
    {
        findEnemy();

    }
}
```

Comment: Please show us what you have tried.

Comment: I add the code .But I think it`s worth nothing.

Comment: First of all yuo have your `FindEnemy()` in update, in my opinion you should only call that when needed, not every frame. Your Array and foreach should be working if you hav enemies with that tag.
I would sugest you do `Debug.Log(respawn.name)` and see which enemies you have in your scene.

Comment: But how can I only call it when needed? Because Enemy is stochastic instantiated at any time. I think I should make FindEnemy() listening all the time. @JorgeSantos

Comment: I think i got it now, you want to spaw PlayerX if you have EnemyX.
You are the one who knows when it should be called. **Maybe call it when the enemy is instantiaded**, because the way you have currently it will infinitly debug stuff, your code is running 24/7 while your scene is playing.
Imagine you have enemy_Red and you want to spawn Player_Red.
In update it will spawn ∞ players.
As for the percentage thing, just do a `int rng = Random.Range(0,100) `
and then `if(rng >= 80) {//do stuff} // this is 20% chance`

Comment: @JorgeSantos You mean I can call it just when the enemy is instantiated , maybe put the code into Enemy.cs, instead of listening all the time because it will cause ∞ ?

Comment: That is a possibility. But i dont know how many Enemy scripts you have.
You could spawn the player along the enemy without needing to see if he exists.
I dont know how your code goes, but imagine you have a method for each enemy spawn.
`void SpawnRed()                   
{                    
  Instantiate....enemyRed;                 
  Instantiate....PlayerRed;                
}                                                   
void SpawnBlue()                        
{                  
  Instantiate....enemyBlue;               
  Instantiate....PlayerBlue;                   
}        
`

Comment: @JorgeSantos Thank you very much! I get it!

Comment: nice  ^.^ , happy coding

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possibility is to let the enemy call findEnemy() of Hero.cs when an it is spawned, either in its Start() or OnAwake() method. Then spawn the hero.

Since these are just normal functions, you can execute whatever logic you want in them, thus being able to chain instantiation of game objects.